# Copying while preserving formatting in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to copy two pages from one Microsoft Word document to another. This changes my formatting, which I am currently trying to fix manually:

- My page margins are different between the old and new document. The margins for only these pages are adjusted using the method [here](https://superuser.com/questions/58676/changing-the-margins-for-an-individual-page-in-word)
- My text changes color, although this is trivially fixed
- My tabs were stuffed up - don't know how to fix this yet

Is there anyway to copy pages from one document to another - exactly as they are?

Comment: You've asked the same question twice.
http://superuser.com/questions/58676/changing-the-margins-for-an-individual-page-in-word

Comment: I was experimenting with trying to separate the question into two parts as these are both very different questions.

Comment: For example the other part is closed, but this part is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My page margins are different between the old and new document and I can't seem to change the formatting for a particular page*

Can't do that this way, sorry. You would need to define a new section, set new margins inside it an then copy/paste it inside.

*My text changes color, although this is trivially fixed*

I didn't see any change in text color while copying text from one document to another.

*Is there anyway to copy pages from one document to another - exactly as they are?*

Only for simple cases ... I find it best to copy text from one document to an empty document, remove all formatting, and then copy it to a new document, and then quickly format it. This may not be acceptable to you, though.

*Another alternative to my problem is to change the page margins for an individual page. I will ask if this is possible in another question.*

See above, requires some work though (if you need it, best do it at start before editing).

Comment: Do you know how to insert a section break in Word 2007?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/word/HA100310731033.aspx. Oh, its in page layout, rather than insert

Comment: I *love* the new toolbars too, yes :)