# Changing the margins for an individual page in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to change the margins for an individual page in Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In word 2007: Page Layout / Breaks / Section breaks / Next page (or any of the other ...) / Margins / Custom margins / Make sure it says "Apply to this section" / Change margins for every section individually.

May I ask, what kind of a document you're making that has different margins on every page ?

Comment: Just the first page of my thesis need to be a title page

Answer (score 10):

1. On the File menu, click Page Setup, and then click the Margins tab.
   Under Margins, select the options you want.
2. To change the default margins, click Default after you select new margin settings. The new default settings are saved in the template on which the document is based. Each new document based on that template automatically uses the new margin settings.
3. To change the margins for part of a document, select the text, and then set the margins you want. In the Apply to box, click Selected text. Microsoft Word automatically inserts section breaks before and after the text with the new margin settings. If your document is already divided into sections, you can click in a section or select multiple sections and then change the margins.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative could be to alter the relevant paragraphs so that they have more indentation at left and right, or negative values for "outdentation" (no good for top and bottom margins though)